# WP Yoast Seo. Как убрать переменную из title для первой страницы пагинации?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

WP Yoast Seo для формирования тайтлов на страницах пагинации предлагает использовать переменную `%%pagenumber%%`.

Например, чтобы на второй стр. пагинации `title` имел вид:

> Пример title заголовка - страница 2

В редактор сниппета SEO заголовка нужно ввести следующее:

> Пример title заголовка `%%sep%%` страница `%%pagenumber%%`

Проблема в том, что и для ПЕРВОЙ страницы заголовок выводится с `%%pagenumber%%`:

> Пример title заголовка - страница 1

---

**Вопрос: Как для первой страницы не выводить/удалить "- страница 1" ?**

Включена "Принудительная перезапись заголовков".

Comment: Как это выглядит в html/css?

Comment: `<title>Пример заголовка - Заказать пример товара - страница 1</title>`

Очевидно решение нужно искать не в html и css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При генерации title в файле class-frontend.php плагин Yoast вызывает хук

```
apply_filters( 'wpseo_title', $title )
```

Вставьте в functions.php обработку этого хука:

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'my_wpseo_title');
function my_wpseo_title($title) {
    $title = str_replace(' - страница 1', '', $title);
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Только Вы забыли return $title, считаем что это проверка меня на внимательность)) Спасибо!

Comment: А Вы не знаете, с учетом того, что включена принудительная перезапись заголовков, возможно ли как-то глобально, для всех страниц пагинации добавлять в тайтл номер страницы?

Сейчас нужно в каждую запись, в каждую рубрику отдельно, руками в редакторе сниппета дописывать переменную %%pagenumber%% в seo заголовок.

Comment: Думаю, такого глобального хука там нет.